ICP Localization algorithm for self-driving car
Suppose I have a point clouds from Lidar (1000 frames), I have a point cloud of the map, where car drives and ground truth labels (x,y,z roll,pitch and yaw).
What is the algorithm (pseudocode) of localize a car in a given map? I didn't find any concrete example
P.S I know this question is not directly about robot, but for convenience "car" can be substituted by "robot".

Hi I believe you can use NDT from Autoware Repository.
Autoware.Universe NDT tutorial
Tier IV repo
Customized Autoware's NDT repo
There is a class about how to localize using this algorithm for self-driving car in ROS2 : Autoware Classes
They also mention ICP algorithm in this class, but it seems the NDT is the most widely used in community (more tutorials and packages available for this sort of algorithm).
